# Timer setDelay() issue in Jython Music

Tags: jython-music

I've noticed that Jython Environment for Music (JEM) has its own Timer implementation, as documented at https://jythonmusic.me/timer-library/ . The documentation shows a function t.setDelay(delay), where *delay* is in milliseconds.

My issue is, **t.setDelay(delay)** appears to make no difference to the delay time. The timer continues on using the original delay which was set at the time of creation.

I am wondering if this is a bug (perhaps got broken during another update?), or if there's a trick to it that I'm not seeing.

Code: my code is part of a larger class. Relevant lines are:

in __init__

```
    self.t = Timer(500, self.metronome, (), True)
```

in self.metronome()

```
     required_delay = int(60000.0/self.adjusted_16count)
     self.t.setDelay(required_delay)
```

The metronome() function continues to recur at the original tempo (in this case, every 500ms) irrespective of the setDelay() function. Weirdly, if I look at the delay value by adding

```
    print self.t.getDelay()
```

after the above code, it shows the correct value (125 in my case), but it physically continues to operate as if the original value is in force. I have confirmed this experimentally by setting very long and very short initial values with an observable outcome (sound) - the period between sounds stays the same as per the original value, even though *getDelay()* shows a change.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the problem is with the Timer class implementation (although it could have been...)  The following works just fine (i.e., it changes the Timer's delay time).

```
from timer import *

delay = 1000

def echo(x):
   print x,

t = Timer(delay, echo, ["."])
t.start()

# change this delay as desired, while the program is running, via JEM's
# live-coding functionality (i.e., Run/Run current line)...
t.setDelay(2000)
```

I think the problem may be elsewhere.  Try this and see...